# I can't submit multiple images with django

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views

I have tried to submit multiple images to my Django website without using Django forms but I can't seem to get it working.
I have watched multiple tutorials doing the exact same thing but it's not working.
Can you please simplify the answers please, Thank you.

## views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def addlisting(request):
    if request.user.is_realtor == True:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            
            header_image = request.FILES.getlist('header_image')

            
            property_images = request.FILES.getlist('property_images')
            for image in property_images:
                image.save()



            description = request.POST['description']
            built_on = request.POST['built_on']
            video_link = request.POST['video_link']
            agent = request.user
            

            new_property = Property.objects.create(
      
                
                full_bathrooms=full_bathrooms, 
                half_bathrooms=half_bathrooms, 
                one_quarter_bathrooms=one_quarter_bathrooms, 
                three_quarter_bathrooms=three_quarter_bathrooms, 
                garage=garage, 
                lot_size=lot_size, 
                yard_size=yard_size, 
                header_image=header_image, 
                description=description, 
                built_on=built_on, 
                video_link=video_link, 
                agent=agent,
            )
            new_property.save()
            

        return render(request, 'dashboard-add-listing.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

## html

```
 <div class="dasboard-widget-box   fl-wrap">
                                <div class="custom-form">
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="header-image">
                                        <div class="upload-options upload-options-header">
                                            <label class="file-upload-label">
                                                <input class="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="header_image">
                                                <span>Upload Header Image</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="listsearch-input-item fl-wrap">
                                        <div class="fuzone">
                                            <div class="fu-text">
                                                <span><i class="far fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Click here or drop files to upload</span>
                                                <div class="photoUpload-files fl-wrap"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="file" name="property_images"  class="upload" multiple>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

## models.py

I have added the models

```
class Property(models.Model):
    header_image = models.FileField(upload_to='property_header_images/')
    property_image = models.FileField(upload_to='property_images/')
def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: It's because you are not saving your image to any model. Like where they `image.save()` will save the image?

Comment: Kindly add your full `Property` model in your question to make it more clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved still not working

Comment: I didn't posted any answer or solution yet.

Comment: I corrected the image.save to create the image instance in property before saving....I thought that was what you meant.

Comment: ` for image in property_images:
                image.save()` where this `image.save()` is going to save the image